# Identiying emails using Regex with ?subject and &body paramters

Tags: c#, regex

My email string looks something like this;

```
reply.2542A7CD0.EDB.2B.EAE39628@spam-email.co.uk?subject='Unsubscribe LIST email@provider.com'&body=Unsubscribe
```

I am currently using the following Regex to get email addresses from a string. It currently only correctly works where the `?subject` and `&body` parameters do not exist.

```
string pat = @"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9_]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$";
```

I am trying to extract the email, subject and body from the above. So using the example provided, the output should be;

```
email = reply.2542A7CD0.EDB.2B.EAE39628@spam-email.co.uk
subject = Unsubscribe LIST email@provider.com
body = Unsubscribe
```

However, because `?subject` and `&body` exist, the above regex does not hit. The above regex works when only the email is present, for example; `reply.2542A7CD0.EDB.2B.EAE39628@spam-email.co.uk`

I need a solution that works for two scenarios;

- When only the email address is present
- When the email address + ?subject parameter is present
- When the email address + ?subject + &body parameters are present

Whole code;

```
var email_string = Regex.Match(header, @"(?<=\<mailto:).[^>]*").Value;

string pat = @"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9_]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$";

var email = Regex.Match(email_string, pat).Value;
var subject = Regex.Match(email_string, "(?<=subject=).[^&]*").Value;
var body = Regex.Match(email_string, "(?<=body=).[^&]*").Value;
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/324Ixs/1)?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a non-regex solution, take a look at the code below:

```
string information = "reply.2542A7CD0.EDB.2B.EAE39628@spam-email.co.uk?subject='Unsubscribe LIST email@provider.com'&body=Unsubscribe";

string[] split = information.Split('?', '&', '=');

string email = split[0];
string subject = split[2];
string body = split[4];
```

A working example of this can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/Jk7tVc).
This will simply split up the string using `string.Split(params char[])` and identify what you want.

**Warning** - this will only work if your initial string is in the exact same format as the given example.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex ends with an $. This means your expression has to match the whole line. This should work:

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9_]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<email>^[^?]*)\?(?:subject='(?<subject>[^']*)')?(?:&?body=(?<body>.*))?
```

see [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/324Ixs/2)

Comment: This doesn't work. The ?subject and &body parameters are not always present. Sometimes it is just only the email address. I need a universal solution to cater for both scenarios.

Comment: @JakeEvans then you can make it optional using `?`